# Detect whether package is being run as a program within __init__.py

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I have a Python package with an `__init__.py` that imports some things to be exposed as the package API.

```py
# __init__.py

from .mymodule import MyClass
# ...
```

I also want to be able to use the package as a command-line application, as in `python -m mypackage`, so I have a `__main__.py` file for that purpose:

```py
# __main__.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from .main import main
    main()
```

So far so good. The problem is that, when the package is run as a program like this, I want to be able to do some stuff *before* importing any of the submodules - namely changing some environment variables before some third-party dependencies are loaded.

I do not know how to do this, at least not in a reasonable way. Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```py
# __init__.py

def thePackageIsRunningAsAnApplication():
    # ???

def prepareEnvironment():
    # ...

if thePackageIsRunningAsAnApplication():
    prepareEnvironment()

from .mymodule import MyClass
# ...
```

The problem is I don't think `thePackageIsRunningAsAnApplication()` can be implemented. The usual `__name__ == '__main__'` does not work here, because the main module being run is `__main__.py`, not `__init__.py`. In fact, I would prefer to define and run `prepareEnvironment` within `__main__.py`, but I don't know how to get that to run before the inner modules are loaded by `__init__.py`.

I *might* (not sure, actually) work around it by lazily loading dependencies on my module, or somehow delaying the internal module loading or something, but I would prefer to avoid doing something like that just for this.

EDIT: Thinking more about it, lazy loading probably would not work either. In the example, `MyClass` is, well, a class, not a submodule, so I cannot lazily load it. Moreover, `MyClass` happens to inherit from a class from that third-party dependency I was mentioning, so I cannot even define it without loading it.

Comment: Maybe using [`dotenv`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) could be useful, as long as your configuration steps aren't too difficult, you can have everything in a file and load that at runtime.

Comment: @NathanFurnal Thanks, `dotenv` seems convenient, but I'm not sure it can solve my problem as such. I still have the issue that I would want to run `load_dotenv` before `from .mymodule import MyClass` but only if the package is being run as a command line application (calling `load_dotenv` in my `__main__.py` would be too late for me).

Comment: That sounds dumb but could you move all the imports in the `main()` function?

Comment: @NathanFurnal No, that's not dumb at all. The reason why I do it in `__init__.py` though is that I still want to be able to use the package as a library with its API if I import it from another Python module. I was just trying something around `from . import __main__` in `__init__.py`, but it's tricky, because there really is no way to tell whether the package `__main__.py` is the program to run until _after_ `__init__.py` has finished running.

Comment: Indeed that's pretty annoying :/

Comment: I can't really follow what the difficulty is with the timing or the order of operations. Could you show an [mre] (including command-line commands to run) illustrating why, if you just do the "some stuff" in `__main__.py` before the `main()` call, it doesn't have the desired effect?

Comment: If I may, what would be the reason to have a CLI part of the package? Why can't the CLI be a separate script that will setup the ENV before importing the package?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem is that anything I do on `__main__.py` (before `main()` or wherever) will run after `__init__.py` has run completely. If you want to test it yourself, you can make a directory `mypackage` with an `__init__.py` and a `__main__.py`, put `print`s on each of them and, from the parent directory, run `python -m mypackage`. You should see that the prints from `__init__.py` run before those of `__main__.py`.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Yes, that would probably the "proper" solution, assuming that it is not possible to do it the way I want. In my case, it would be more convenient to me to be able to run it as I describe, because I have a directory (in my Python path) with a bunch of independent, self-contained packages, and I would prefer to avoid maintaining an additional script that I have to put in my `PATH`. I guess I can always have the runnable part in another package or module that has `mypackage` as a dependency and does the environment preparation before loading it.

Comment: @jdehesa It seam that you are trying to solve a problem that doesent exist. I can't think of a good solution(without digging into the abyss) and I dont see why having another script would be a problem, you have to maintain it ether way wether it's part of the package or not. It just seems to me like a whole lot of trouble to solve this your way.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Yes, that is what I meant. As I said, I would **prefer** to have it work as I intended, for convenience, if it can be done through _reasonable_ means (which is what I am asking about in the question). E.g., I would consider a solution if it just involved using something like [`LazyLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.LazyLoader) (which I don't think it actually can help in this specific case), but obviously I am not going to, say, fork my own version of Python to get this to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make sense to add a separate entry point for running your code as a script, rather than using `__main__.py`, which as you've noticed, can only be run after the package's `__init__.py` is fully loaded.

A simple script like `run_mypackage.py` located at the top level could contain the environment variable tweaking code, and then could import and run the package afterwards.

```
def prepare_environment():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prepare_environment()            # adjust the environment firstt

    from mypackage.main import main  # then load the package afterwards
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, I was just mentioning in the comments that an external script (or even another "app" package that has `mypackage` as a dependency) would probably be the proper way of doing this. I preferred to have everything self-contained into the same package, like e.g. [`http`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) package which you can use from code and from CLI, but I don't think it's possible for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want to do pre-import wise.

Afaik there is no preprocessor step before imports.
In other languages than python there usually are compiler flags which can be read before imports are done but i don't know if python has those to.

I possible solution to do stuff pre-import wise could be to have a seperate package that is imported before your other submodules (ofcourse you would need some kind of switch to not have it run when you call/use the package the usual external way).
At import of the package the whole package is run (if there is no **name** == '**main**' part) which can be used to do stuff before the other modules are importet.
But if you mean solving some environment issues when your programm is called on the different way i think there is no way for having multi-importpath resolution without ambiguity.
There are relative import paths if your package is locally saved but i don't think they can be used that way.
Would be some interesting experiment though.

Comment: I just want to set some environment variables before my imports in the case the package is run as a command line application (like `os.environ['SOME_VAR'] = 'SOME_VALUE'`). That "switch" that you mention is indeed exactly what I need, but I'm not sure there is a good way to implement it.

Comment: Well in that case you can easily use the "__name == '__main'" routine. "__name" is only "__main" if the .py file is run directly in commandline. If it is run in a package "__name" will not be '__main'. And if you only want to set os.environ variables on direct call you can put os.environ-commands into the "__name" == '__main' block. (sorry for misspelling the name == main part but the underscores in comments trigger italic or bold font)

Comment: on Nathan Furnals comment on the topic of imports in the main() function (dynamic imports):
Yes that is possible. Have a look at the following article about advanced import techniques:
https://realpython.com/python-import/#dynamic-imports

Comment: Indeed, I can use `__name__ == '__main__'` on `__main__.py`,  which is the "main" file that is run when I type `python -m mypackage` on the command line, but not in `__init__.py`, which runs always before `__main__.py` (as part of the initial implicit importing of `mypackage`) and is the point where I would like to be able to change the environment variables.